# How can I get the id of a product that generates Woocommerce add to cart message?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display multiple items (each with their own add to card button) on a single page; so that the buyer can add items to cart without going to an individual page.

I need to have the add to cart message displayed in the individual product's container. I am using `wc_print_notices()` call inside the price section of the loop for each product, but this only puts the message inside the first product instead of the one that triggered it.

Is there a way to check which product id generates the `$message` string? so that I might do some sort of if statement to call `wc_print_notices()` based on which add to cart button triggered it?

Comment: No, the notices are stored as an array of arrays, and only sorted by type.

Answer (score -1):

According to your requirement there is already a shop page provided be woo-commerce, from there buyer can add multiple product to cart, I guess you are showing some featured product in your single page, there within the product loop call this snippet to get add-to-cart button

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( $product->id ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
    esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),
$product );
```

you must define the `$product` object before calling above code snippet.